# My Emulator won't unlock

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I created a brand new emulator today but it is behaving weird today. Here is my setting:

[image]

When i start it up, it loads fine. Until it gets to the lock screen. I keep on dragging/swiping from bottom to top to unlock, but it wont! This is the first time I encountered such behaviour. I tried with target `Android 6.0 - API Level 23` but was able to unlock. I want to test my app on Google API 23. Please help to figure out the proper setting values.

Comment: Try to restart the computer, don't know if it sounds silly.

Comment: time like this, nothing sounds silly. but it did not work.

Comment: Another silly question then, are you sure it is unlocking from bottom to top? Have you tried installing another emulator? What if you press the buttons that the emulator has on the side? Any errors in logcat or wherever? does HAXM works properly?

Comment: i am sure it is from bottom to top because `Android 6.0 - API Level 23` target works that way. and there is nothing helpful on the side buttons.

Comment: i edited my above comment added some questions

Comment: does it say something on lock screen?

Comment: nothing. HAXM works fine I believe. Before this won't load up because the HAXM needs to be updated. I updated, now it works and start up without any errors. I just can't unlock the screen. It is as if you need to drag the screen from bottom all the way to the top.

Comment: try pressing F2 or Page Up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still did not solve this problem, somewhat. To get thru, what I did was I activated the Camera emulation then relaunched the emulator. On the lock screen, I dragged the Camera icon. The camera would crash and emulator would notify you about it thru a pop up dialog. Once you exit the dialog, it will go back to your homepage UNLOCKED! I know, it was weird but it worked.

Answer (score 5):

Happened to me as well.

Another solution in addition to what @TTRansmit suggested is as below:

1. Close emulator.
2. Go to AVD manager screen, edit your Emulator and go to `Advanced Settings`.
3. Select `Cold boot` as Boot option located in `Emulated Performance` section. This way you will be able to restart your emulator and get it unlocked without loosing data.

Answer (score 1):

Power off (via holding power) on the device buttons and wipe data (from Android Virtual Device Manager) worked for me. It was turning off the Device Frame from the edit/Virtual Device Configuration screen of AVD that seemed to cause the problem.