# The android emulator remains unlocked after I insert the pin code

Tags: android-emulator

Out of blue the android emulator with google play services API 27 did not unlock its screen. After I insert the password on Mac Mojave I get back the lock screen instead of accessing to the device. I try to swipe up but does not work.

I tried without success to uninstall the emulator, to wipe data, as I found in this other post [My Emulator won't unlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39589269/my-emulator-wont-unlock). Is this a known bug? I cannot find official google list where people complain about this issue, so I am wondering what I did wrong. I have also tried to activate the camera, but does not work as suggested in the above mentioned post.

I expect that when I insert the just password the emulator is unlocked, the just password is `0000` and I do not get a wrong pin message, but a black screen for 800 milliseconds and then the lock screen with some notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try wiping the data and reboot. Or try creating a new emulator with Nexus5X with Android28 or other.

When you try to start the emulator from Android Studio, in the AVD manager, select the drop down and Wipe Data.